# Extracting Url from the html page Beautiful Soup/Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying ot fetch href based on the argument which i pass..for example test.py arg1 arg2 ...where arg1 is school name something like "south carolina" so it has to retrieve the score according to the school given in the argument.
Here is a small snippet from the prettified source which i saved using urlopen and BeautifulSoup.

```
<a data-ylk="lt:s;sec:mod-sch;slk:game;itc:0;ltxt:;tar:sports.yahoo.com;" 
  href="/ncaaf/south-carolina-gamecocks-georgia-bulldogs-201309070068/">
<span class="away "> 30 </span>
 -
<span class="home winner"> 41 </span> </a>
```

Now the arg1 should match with href provided so that i can retrieve the score.. I used

```
bs.find('a', href="/ncaaf/south-carolina-gamecocks-georgia-bulldogs-201309070068/")
```

But what if I have to match my argument such as south carolina to href..How can I match it? something like `href="/ncaaf/south-carolina-*` so that I can fetch whole href just by matching with argument1 (which I will be replacing with hyphens) and also if I give "gerorgia" is it possible to retrieve the href just by matching the argument regardless of the position of the string after /ncaaf/............./

As I'm poor in regex ,it's bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

You'd indeed have to match that with a regular expression.

If your command-line argument is of the form `south-carolina` in `sys.argv[1]`, use:

```
 import re

 school_name = sys.argv[1]
 url_pattern = re.compile(r'/ncaaf/{}-'.format(re.escape(school_name)))

 matching_links = soup.find_all('a', href=url_pattern)
```

The `re.escape()` makes sure that any characters in the input that could be interpreted as regular expression meta-characters are properly escaped.

For `south-carolina` that'd result in the pattern `/ncaaf/south-carolina-` which matches anything *containing* the literal text `/ncaaf/south-carolina-`; you don't really need to include any wild-card characters as for a `re.search()` match text containment is enough.

Comment: what if my cli argument is of the form "south carolina" and it isn't true all the time school name is in the first place after /ncaaf/south-carolina-.......what if the school name is something like this /ncaaf/albany-south-carolina..is there any dynamic of pulling it..regardless of the position after /ncaaf/..

Comment: @relax: Replace spaces with dashes; `school_name = school_name.lower().replace(' ', '-')` would lowercase it as well.

Comment: thanks @Martijn , one last question for example in this `href="/ncaaf/south-carolina-gamecocks-georgia-bulldogs-201309070068/`    what if my argument is "georgia" does it work with `r'/ncaaf/{}-'.format(re.escape(school_name)` regex...if not do i have to use any othere regex for this to match the string regardless of position

Comment: It won't match; it'll only match URLS with `/ncaaf/georgia-` in them. You could add a wildcard in but I fear you'll get a lot of false positives instead.